# Java 8 Streams Count all Keys

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a file that contains data in the form of JSON format. I am reading it line by line and every line has 1 JSON record so the format is really not an issue. Below is an example line:

```
{"url": "http://ldrlongdistancerider.com/bikers_rights_motorcycle/rightsriders0163.php", "timestamp": 1257072412, "tags": ["nscensorship", "cloudmark", "network", "solutions", "content", "based", "spam", "signatures"]}
```

What I need to do is count all the duplicate URLs and print it like:

```
 http://ldrlongdistancerider.com/bikers_rights_motorcycle/rightsriders0163.php"  1
```

How can I achieve this using streams? By the way, I need to filter the records based on the timestamp. So if someone passed a range of dates, I would have to count the URLs falling in that range. I have done most of it but this counting part is confusing to me.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
for (Path filePath : files) {
        try {
            Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath.toUri()))
                 .filter(s -> Link.parse(s).timestamp() > startSeconds)
                 .filter(s -> Link.parse(s).timestamp() < stopSeconds)
                 .forEach(s -> countMap.put(Link.parse(s).url(), 1));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

countMap is HashMap of String, Integer

Comment: You could use `map(Link::parse)` to avoid parsing everything three times.

Comment: I can't really as I need to filter the URLs based on the timestamp provided first. Using a method reference won't really give me what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're parsing multiple times, and you're altering an external map instead of letting the stream create the map for you, which is an anti-pattern (it makes it hard to make the stream parallel)

You could just use

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath.toUri()))
     .map(Link::parse)
     .filter(link -> link.timestamp() > startSeconds && link.timestamp() < stopSeconds)
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Link::url, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
countMap = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath.toUri()))
                 .filter(s -> Link.parse(s).timestamp() > startSeconds)
                 .filter(s -> Link.parse(s).timestamp() < stopSeconds)
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x ->Link.parse(x).url()))
                 .entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> entry.getValue().size()));
```

That's what I ended up doing and it works. Yeah, I needed to work on the parsing issue @JB Nizet